# Image Banish from the bin folder

Tags: java

I am following this tutorial http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/collision/

Here I have to put my images in the bin folder. It works perfect. But when I shutdown my computer sometimes the images files are banished from the bin folder. Why this is occuring and how can I solve this.
Thank You

Comment: every java project contains a bin folder

Comment: It depends on your IDE. If you think all the java projects that are created by and IDE contains a bin folder it is completely wrong.

Comment: oops. may be it wrong. because I always use Eclipse IDE and it always creates a bin folder. Thank you for your information

Comment: Don't put your stuffs in bin folder. bin folder will be re created every time you clean and build the project. So then everything that you store there will be lost

Answer (score 1):

Well, are you using any kind of IDE to compile your code? If so, it is possible, that "bin" folder is actually configured like an "output folder" for the compilation... and that the IDE is allowed to clenaup such folder when rebuilding the project from scratch.

If that is your case, what I advice you to do is to leave the bin folder alone and place your image in a "source folder" instead. A good practice is to have a different souce folder from the one you have your *.java files in (I usually use src/main/java for java files and src/main/resources for other kind of stuff).

When compiling, the IDE usually just copies what is placed in the source folder (and doesn't need to be compiled) into the output folder.

Comment: I am using this code to read the image                         private String craft = "/resources/alien.png";                      ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(craft));   and i can not able to read image from another folder

Comment: If you place your image in a source folder the IDE will copy the image to the bin (output) folder after compiling and when running your code you will be reading the copy of such image in the bin folder.